# How to express "help someone with X"

Tags: expressions

I helped someone fix something, and I'd like to try and express that it was mostly the other person doing the work and I just provided assistance.

The best I can come up with is 「問題の解決に田中さんを手伝いました」but I feel like this is wrong.

Comment: Why do you feel it's wrong? If I were saying it, I might break it into two smaller sentences to make it easier on myself.

Comment: Who are you trying to say this to? 田中さん or someone else?

Answer (score 5):

I would say...

> 「［Someone］の［Something］を手伝う」 "help [someone] with [something]"
>    「［Someone］が［Verb］のを手伝う」 "help [someone] [do something]"

A few examples:

> 田中さんの仕事を手伝いました。
>   田中さんの日本語の宿題を手伝いました。
>   田中さんが問題を解決するのを手伝いました。
>   田中さんがレポートを書くのを手伝いました。